# Dafny verification - refer to original var in post condition

Tags: dafny

I am trying to verify my code in Dafny and I encountered a problem:
I have a method that is iterating over a sequence and changes it. The method changes the sequence according to the elements in the sequence. I would like to add a post condition like this: "if the elements in the sequence are X then something should happen". The problem is that the method changes the set (adds element etc.) and I want to check the condition of the original sequence. Is there an elegant way of doing that in Dafny? (The only way I could think of right now is keeping global var of the original condition of the sequence, but I am looking for the right way of doing that).

Code example:

```
method changeSeq(p: class1, s: seq<class1>)
ensures |s| == 10 ==> p in s
{
    if (|s| == 10){
        s := s + [p];
    }
}
```

In the code, I want the post condition to check original s stat, and not its stat after we changed it.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `old` for old value of a variable like `s == old(s)`.

Here is one example: http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/fhQgD

From [Dafny Documentation 22.18. Old Expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/blob/master/Docs/DafnyRef/out/DafnyRef.pdf)

> `OldExpression_ = "old" "(" Expression(allowLemma: true, allowLambda: true) ")"`
>
> An *old expression* is used in postconditions. `old(e)` evaluates to the value expression `e` had on entry to the current method. Note that **old** only affects heap dereferences, like `o.f` and `a[i]`. In particular, **old** has no effect on the value returned for local variables or out-parameters.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15027572)

Comment: How can you say that this does not provide answer? I understand the problem and think that this the correct answer.

Comment: Is there some documentation for *old* which you could link to?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation. I came across it via example of Dafny codes. So Here is one that might help understand it: http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/fhQgD

Comment: @Jonathan727 `old()` is documented briefly in section 22.18 of the [Dafny Reference Manual](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/blob/master/Docs/DafnyRef/out/DafnyRef.pdf). You can find examples in the [Dafny test suite](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/tree/master/Test) by searching for "old". For a good, moderately complex example, see [dafny1/Queue.dfy](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/blob/master/Test/dafny1/Queue.dfy).